# assign object from the list using its index

Tags: c#, .net

If I have list of Author objects like

```
List<Author> authors = new List<Author>{ 
       new  Author { Id = 1, Name = "John Freeman"};
       new  Author { Id = 1, Name = "Adam Kurtz"};
};
```

this example is actually wrapped in static method which returns list of authors.

Inside my other object there is property `Authors` of type `List<Author>`. 
Now I want to assign second author from the list to `Authors` property.

I thought that I can use `Authors = GetAuthors()[1].ToList()`;
but I cannot access ToList() on index specified author.

to clarify

```
private static List<Author> GetAuthors() return list of authors (example above). 
var someObject = new SomeObject()
{
   Authors = // select only Adam Kurtz author using index 
             // and assign to Authors property of type List<Author>
};
```

Comment: not sure I understand your question do you need  `Authors = new List<Author>(){someObject[1]};` ?

Comment: I just needed to instance new List<Author>() and than assing index specified author, like it was answered below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want a `List<Author>` with a single author in it. Using `ToList()` on a single `Author` object is then not valid syntax.

Try this: `Authors = new List<Author>() { GetAuthors()[1] };`

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a single author to `list<Author>`, so you will have to create a list (of single author) to assign it..

```
Authors = new List<Author>() {GetAuthor()[1]};
```

I don't know, why you want to take based on index, ideally you should write a query based on `ID` of author to get value, so that it won't create any issue in future..

Like: `Authors = new List<Author>() {GetAuthor().FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID==2)};`

Answer (score 0):

A sollution with LINQ would be
`GetAuthors().Skip(1).Take(1)`

Edit: Ignore all that. You're working with lists.
What you *actually* need is to use `GetRange`:

`GetAuthors().GetRange(1,1);`